# Media Queries in CSS are not working properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I Tried to do 2 navigations, when the width is over 481 it activates the desktop version and for lower the mobile version. But its not properly working, what i try to say its not working at all how it seems. It changed something but i can't see the different. It still shows me both navigations in mobile and in Desktop Version it shows me the Desktop Navigation and under this it shows me a ul list with unformatted li links.

i didn't get how to use the code bb-codes ... so i've posted them on pastebin:

[HTML](http://pastebin.com/1sU4kw9g)

And The CSS part with the Mediaqueries:

[CSS](http://pastebin.com/P0ABFJnp)

I've added the classes to every single element but its still not working, what is wrong here? pls help :/

Answer (score 0):

Media queries won't work properly without viewport meta tag, e.g.:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Looks like your code is missing this.

Comment: No i've already added this in the head, sorry for not mentioning it.